# I want to make a custom class and use it for other activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having the same problem with this question

[How to put events in calendar using recycler view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68715605/how-to-put-events-in-calendar-using-recycler-view-in-android)

//Event.java

```
public class Event implements Serializable
{
    public static ArrayList<Event> eventsList = new ArrayList<>(); //event list
    public static String Event_EDIT_EXTRA = "eventEdit";

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime time;
    private String startdate;
    private String enddate;
    private Date deleted;

    public static ArrayList<Event> eventsForDate(LocalDate date) {
        ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Event event : eventsList)
        {
            // not delete event
            if(event.getDeleted()==null) {
                if (event.getDate().equals(date))
                    events.add(event);
            }
        }
        return events;
    }

    public Event(){}
    public Event (int id, String title, LocalDate date, LocalTime time, String startdate, String enddate, Date deleted)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        .....
    }

class MyDate{

   //What should I do.....?


}
```

I tried a lot but it didn't even work.MyEvent.I'm going to use java in another adapter. Maybe inside the onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android's [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) to interact with a user's calendar.

Also, make sure your application is requesting the proper permissions.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    ...
</manifest>
```